# Java string format returns nothing

Tags: java, formatting, string-formatting

I am trying to get the returned value from a class, however I believe the `string.format()` is causing an error resulting in no value to return.

Class:

```
public class FilterTime {
    public String getData(String day, Integer time){
        // define the result
        String result = "";
        String convertedDay = "";

        if(day == "Friday 30th August"){
            convertedDay = "30";
        }
        if(day == "Saturday 31st August"){
            convertedDay = "31";
        }
        if(day == "Sunday 1st September"){
            convertedDay = "01";
        }

        if(time == null){
            result = "http://www.website.org/json.php?f=%s&type=date".format(convertedDay);
            Log.d("RESULT", "r:" + result);
        }else{
            result = "http://www.website.org/json.php?f=%s&time=@d&type=dateAndTime".format(convertedDay, time);
            Log.d("RESULT", "r:" + result);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

When I trace result in my Activity:

```
FilterTime filterTime = new FilterTime();
String filteredURL = filterTime.getData(dayFilter, timeFilter);
```

When I trace filteredURL it returns nothing at all. So I then put the `Log.d()` into the class and I found that when tracing the following it also returns nothing:

```
if(time == null){
                result = "http://www.website.org/json.php?f=%s&type=date".format(convertedDay);
                Log.d("RESULT", "r:" + result);
            }else{
                result = "http://www.website.org/json.php?f=%s&time=@d&type=dateAndTime".format(convertedDay, time);
                Log.d("RESULT", "r:" + result);
            }
```

I cannot understand where the error is coming from because there are no errors, just a warning  saying it should be accessed in a static way, but I think the error resides in the if statement.

Comment: `day == "Friday 30th August"` <-- NO. this compares the references, NOT the contents. To compare the contents, use `.equals()`: `day.equals("...")`. Archi duplicate SO question, that one.

Answer (score 3):

Use [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) to compare the contents of the `String` :

> Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

Hence change your code to :

```
if("Friday 30th August".equals(day)){
        convertedDay = "30";
}
```

`==` operator compares object references, variable which contains a reference to an object. It checks if the references point to the same object.

**P.S.:-** Invoked `equals()` on the String literal to avoid any NPE due to *null* `day`.

Comment: Oh right! I didnt realise this was the problem!! What's the difference between a reference and the value?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160485/object-vs-reference-in-java) .

Comment: So it is kinda like a pointer?

Comment: Not exactly but yes you can assume that.

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect `String` comparison, instead of `==` use `equals`.

`format` is printing nothing since `convertedDay` remains empty `""` due to invalid `String` comparison.

Answer (score 0):

[String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) is a static method.  Don't call it on a String object, just call it directly like this:

```
String.format("http://www.website.org/json.php?f=%s&type=date", convertedDay);
```

That should do the formatting like you wanted