# What is meaning of class obj =obj1;

Tags: java, object

I have a class like

```
public class fun{

     abc(){//.some code.//}

}
```

and in some `main` method there is code like

```
fun obj = new fun();
fun obj1 = obj;
```

Please help me explain object in `main` how the access class.

Comment: Sorry but can you clarify which part confuses you? Are you familiar with terms: type, variable, reference, declaration, assignment operator?

Comment: Actually I want to ask if i use obj1.abc() will it call obj abc() or its own obj1 abc()

Comment: `obj` and `obj1` are separate variables so they hold its own separate data, but that data can be same as other data. Like in case of `int x = 1; int y = x;` `y` variable would hold its own copy of value held by `x` which would mean it would also hold `1`, but this would be separate than `1` held by `x`. Same applies for references which are just objects IDs (number which JVM can use to locate object). When you write `fun obj1 = obj;` you create separate variable `obj1` and assign to it copy of reference (object ID) held by variable `obj`. So now both `obj` and `obj1` hold ID to same object.

Comment: This means when you call `obj1.abc()` JVM will use reference from `obj1` to locate the object and then call `abc()` method on it. Here you will get same result as if you would call `obj.abc()` because `obj` holds separate coby of reference which points JVM to *same* object so any changes done by `abc()` method would affect that common object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java there are two different things:

1) Reference Variable

2) Object

**Reference Variable:** It is stored in stack they can be contained in other objects (then they are not really variables, but fields), which puts them on the heap also. It is a variable that points to some object in memory.

**Object:** Objects are stored in heap memory. It is an instance of class that is dynamically created.

Here in your code `obj` and `obj1` are reference variables. When you do `fun obj=new fun()`, you are creating Object of fun class and obj points to that object in memory. And in next line when you call `fun obj1=obj`, now the `obj1` is also pointing to same object which is being pointed by obj.

So technically both are pointing to same memory on heap. `obj == obj1` will be evaluated to `true`.

**Note :** Reference and Object definition [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18399479/4762502).

(Thanks to [pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393766/pshemo) for this info) And reference and reference variable is not the same thing. Reference (at least in Java) is unique number assigned to each object which can be used to find it by JVM. Reference variable is variable of type which can store references (as their value).

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that *reference* and *reference variable* is not the same thing. Reference (at least in Java) is unique number assigned to each object which can be used to find it by JVM. Reference variable is variable of type which can store references (as their value).

Answer (score 0):

You posted this code as what's in your `main` method:

```
fun obj = new fun();
fun obj1 = obj;
```

The first line is doing a few things...

- `new fun();` is calling the constructor on class `fun` (which separately you should use a capital "F" to follow standard Java naming conventions). This will create a new instance of the `fun` class, so there will be one `fun` object.
- `fun obj = ...` that is defining a variable named `obj` which holds a reference to a `fun` object. An alternative might be `String s` which would define a variable `s` that references a `String` object. Also, after this line is done, `obj` will point at the actual Java object that was created by calling `new fun();`.

The second line:

- creates a new variable - `obj1` - that references a `fun` object
- points `obj1` at the same underlying object that `obj` points to

So in the end, you have one object – the thing created from `new fun()` – and two variables that reference that same object.